# Creating a deck of poker card without using array method

Tags: java

I have a task I need help with.

The task is about making a deck of poker cards without using array method but the problem is I know how to use array but lecturer told me to not use it and should only use class and constructor.

Here is my code:

```
public class PokerCard {
private String rank;
private String suit;

//Create Constructor for PokerCard
public PokerCard(){
    rank = "Undefined";
    suit = "Undefined";  
}//End PokerCard
//-------------------------------------------------

//Getters
public String getRank() {return rank;}
public String getSuit() {return suit;}
//--------------------------------------------------

//Settlers 
public void setRank(String r){
    rank = r;
}//END setRank

public void setSuit(String s){
    suit = s;
}//END setSuit
//---------------------------------------------------

public PokerCard(PokerCard card){
    rank = card.getRank();
    suit = card.getSuit();
}//END Rectangle
//---------------------------------------
//END PokerCard
```

Right now, I don't know how to initialize the rank and suit into it.

I just need pointers on how to do it and I don't need a source code example.
I will figure out the source code myself.
Also, you can point out any mistakes in my code too.
Thank you.

Comment: Why cant you use parameterised constructor with deck and suit values passed to it ?

Comment: @PraveenE How do I use parameterised constructor? Sorry, I just learnt about class method last week and I am still a little blurr.

Comment: Which chapter did you learn before? This example either wants to show the usage of implementations of `AbstractList` or you should implement a linked list!

Comment: I learnt loop before this chapter

Comment: I think the lecturer wants you to use enum type for rank and suit instead of String.

Comment: @KshitijDhakal Ah yes, he did say something about using enums. Thanks for the reminder